# Passing a device to a container running on rootless Docker

Tags: docker

I have set up rootless Docker per instructions on a Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, and am trying to run the zigbee2mqtt container using a serial device on the host machine. The user running the Docker service is also part of the dialout group on the host and can access the serial device without problems. The issue happens when I try to access it in the container:

```bash
$ docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh --device /dev/ttyACM0 koenkk/zigbee2mqtt -c "ls -halt /dev/ttyACM0"
crw-rw----    1 nobody   nobody    166,   0 Jul 13 20:47 /dev/ttyACM0
```

The user is mapped to "nobody" with id 65534. I get permission denied any way I try to access it in this manner.

The container also has a dialout group with nr 20, but I assume this number is lying because of the user namespace mapping. Adding "--group-add dialout" makes no difference. I was hoping Docker would automagically take care of permissions when passing devices, but it doesn't seem to be. I also cannot change the permissions inside the container, even though I'm the root user and also part of the dialout group, which I suppose doesn't change anything.

Does Docker currently support a way to access devices in this manner? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome :)

I'm afraid I don't have an answer for you, but I've been having the same issue all day. I can at least add more detail to the problem.

[This link here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/43019#issuecomment-1062199525) seems to be a similar situation, the poster in question determined that the issue was related to the USB device in the host machine being owned by root:dialout (UID0 and GID20). But due to the way rootless docker remaps namespaces, dialout becomes something entirely different within the container.

The solution they had was to determine which GID Host20 became in the container and pass that number in with group-add.

This doesn't seem to work for me, because within my container, the host UID:GID of 0:20 actually becomes 65534:65534 (whereas for them it was 65534:65537 so they just had to add 65537 to group-add).

Sorry I've done a shocking job of describing this. I'm still working on it and will post back here with something more intelligible and easy to follow if I figure it out.

---

EDIT: Okay. I think I've figured it out and hopefully it will help.
I'm going to go into *heavy* detail here, not for your sake as it seems like you know a lot of the below, but more for anyone else who comes across this thread and has the same issue we do. 
Also, a HUGE mention has to go to **schklom** from the GitHub thread I linked earlier, his work is the basis for pretty much everything below. However, for me at least, I was unable to achieve his results until I reordered his commands somewhat. I'm posting that revised ordering along with a lot more detail and context here.

**My Context:**

- I'm using a ConBeeII Zigbee stick.
- I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.
- I'm attempting to pass the device into Zigbee2Mqtt container.
- I'm running rootless docker, configured as per their setup guide.
- The user I am running the docker daemon as is called `dockersvcaccount`. It has a UID of `1001`.
- My ConBeeII appears with a device path of `/dev/ttyACM0`.
- My ConBeeII appears with a device serial ID of `/dev/serial/by-id/usb-dresden_elektronik_ingenieurtechnik_GmbH_ConBee_II_DE2488195-if00`.

**Additional notes:** 
I know a lot of the guides will go the easy route and try pass the ConBeeII in with the device path rather than the Serial ID, I'm going to be using the Serial ID in this case, and that's because it's the way suggested by the Zigbee2Mqtt guide, something about the device path not always remaining consistent. I don't know how much of an issue that is in reality, but best practices are best practices.

**On with the show then!** 
The device ownership of the USB is a little weird. If you query it by serial ID, it will show as being owned by user `root` and group `root` (`root:root`):

```
dockersvcaccount@rtlsdocker:~$ ls -l /dev/serial/by-id/usb-dresden_elektronik_ingenieurtechnik_GmbH_ConBee_II_DE2488195-if00
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jul 14 07:40 /dev/serial/by-id/usb-dresden_elektronik_ingenieurtechnik_GmbH_ConBee_II_DE2488195-if00 -> ../../ttyACM0
```

If you perform the same query using the path (the thing we aren't going to use to pass into the container), it shows as being owned by user `root` and group `dialout` (`root:dialout`):

```
dockersvcaccount@rtlsdocker:~$ ls -l /dev/ttyACM0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Jul 14 07:40 /dev/ttyACM0
```

Honestly, I don't know why this is or what the implications are, maybe someone better versed in Ubuntu's handling of devices can step in and clear it up.

But the important thing to take away is that in **some** aspect, the group with access to the USB device is `dialout`, this is how we are going to get access to it within the docker container. 
Yes, the `root` group has access too but we don't want to expose that within the container, it defeats the point of running rootless docker.

Another key thing to bear in mind is that the `dialout` group on the HOST system (outside the container) has a group ID of 20. If you don't believe me, run the above command again but with the flag `-ln` rather than just `-l`. It will list users and group by their ID rather than name. Where once there was `dialout` now there is `20`.

The issue we are encountering is that when running docker in rootless mode, namespaces get remapped (as do user and group IDs). This is by design as a security feature, but it does mean that it isn't as easy as just passing in `--group-add dialout` as the Zogbee2Mqtt docs suggest. Note that within a container, running `whoami` will return 'root': \

```
dockersvcaccount@rtlsdocker:~$ docker exec -it c_Zigbee2Mqtt sh
/app # whoami
root
/app # id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=65537,0(root),1(bin),2(daemon),3(sys),4(adm),6(disk),10(wheel),11(floppy),20(dialout),26(tape),27(video)
```

However, if we went ahead and created a file, on a volume shared between the container and the host (in this case `/app/shareddir` we would see that UID of 0 (`root`) within the container is actually mapped to UID of 1001 (`dockersvcaccount`) on the host.

```
dockersvcaccount@rtlsdocker:~/zigbee2mqtt/shareddir$ docker exec -it c_Zigbee2Mqtt sh
/app # cd shareddir/
/app/shareddir # touch testdoc.txt
/app/shareddir # ls -ln testdoc.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 0        0                0 Jul 14 20:11 testdoc.txt
/app/shareddir # exit
dockersvcaccount@rtlsdocker:~/zigbee2mqtt/shareddir$ ls -ln testdoc.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001 0 Jul 14 08:11 testdoc.txt
dockersvcaccount@rtlsdocker:~/zigbee2mqtt/shareddir$
```

However, not all user and group ID's are mapped so sensibly, most such as `root` seem to end up mapped to some random number or (in many cases such as ours) to `nobody`. I tested this out by creating three files in the Host machine, owned by groups:

- root (0)
- dockerserviceaccount (1001)
- dialout (20)

When viewed from within the container, these owning group IDs became:

- nobody (65534)
- root (0)
- nobody (65534) 
  respectively.

Note again we have our sensible `dockersvcaccount` == `root` mapping, but for the other two groups `root` and `dialout` they map to `nobody` within the container.

This is our problem, and also where the instructions from the GitHub fall apart, because according to that commenter, they were able to see the `dialout` group from the host mapped to a group ID of `65537` within the container, provide that group to the running user and be off to the races.

The issue as I found it is that you actually have to make the edits he makes to the `/etc/subgid` file on the host machine BEFORE you attempt to see any sensible mapping of host `dialout` inside the container. As far as I can tell, the edits to this file determine which GIDs (group IDs) from the host get mapped "sensibly" within the container. By editing this file to include (in my case): 
`dockersvcaccount:20:1` 
at the bottom of it, I seem to be instructing the system to "sensibly" map the GID of 20 within the container. (The `:1` indicated how many GID's starting at 20 we want to map. We only want to map one in this case.).

After adding this **and rebooting the system** I found that any files made on the host system with the host group ID of 20 were mapping to the GID of `65537` within the container, no longer `nobody`.

```
dockersvcaccount@rtlsdocker:~/zigbee2mqtt/shareddir$ sudo chown 1001:dialout testdoc.txt
dockersvcaccount@rtlsdocker:~/zigbee2mqtt/shareddir$ ls -ln testdoc.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 20 0 Jul 14 08:11 testdoc.txt
dockersvcaccount@rtlsdocker:~/zigbee2mqtt/shareddir$ docker exec -it c_Zigbee2Mqtt sh
/app/shareddir # ls -ln testdoc.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 0        65537            0 Jul 14 20:11 testdoc.txt
```

We now have a meaningful GID to map to our user within the container, this will resolve to the GID of 20 outside the container which we know has ownership permissions on our USB device. That means the final step in this plan is to add the below to our docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  zigbee2mqtt:
      group_add:
      - "65537"
```

This will add that group ID within the container to our user within the container.

---

TL;DR: Follow the instructions left behind in the GitHub thread I linked *waaaaaaaaay* at the top, before the EDIT. Just swap things around so you perform the edits to `/etc/subgid` BEFORE trying to do any fancy stuff within the container or else you won't get the same results as he was getting.

Comment: I have decided to use ser2net to expose the serial port as a network service. This way there's no coupling between docker and the host system, and I can use standard network tools to lock access down.